# Prevent gedit from graying out when not in focus, in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gedit

I'm migrating from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and I'm finding this extremely annoying: when gedit is not selected, its text grays out from full black to a paler shade.

Is there some way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This effect is governed by the theme you use. The default Ubuntu 18.04 theme, Ambiance, indeed greys the background and slightly greys the text of windows that are not in focus.

The easiest solution is to go out and find a theme that does not apply such effect. More difficult would be to edit your theme. However, this would involve editing the code of the style sheet.